# kube static egress ip

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

- static-egressip-controller logs the following error:

```
Failed to add egress IP *.*.*.* for the staticegressip test
on the gateway due to failed to find interface.
```

- Kubernetes version 1.14.6;
- CNI plugin flannel
- Environment is Rancher VMware.
- Same issue on Virtualbox Cluster (CNI calico) with ubuntu nodes.
- Full log:

```
Successfully synced 'test' Updating StaticEgressIP: test Processing update
 to StaticEgressIP: test Created ipset name: EGRESS-IP-H4BSYLW2DXN7MUR Added ips 
[10.42.3.12 10.42.3.12] to the ipset name: EGRESS-IP-H4BSYLW2DXN7MURD Added rules 
in filter table FORWARD chain to permit traffic iptables rule in mangle table 
PREROUTING chain to match src to ipset Failed to add egress IP 192.168.56.102 
for the staticegressip test on the gateway due to failed to find interface.
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more context (i.e. component versions, full log, environment description).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve a time to read the  [**about page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit these links to learn [**how to ask a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better and faster answer! Providing the necessary details, including yamls, versions, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!